# Stability of Mathieu equation: $x''(t)+\cos t \,x(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions, stability-in-odes

The equation
$$
x''(t)+\cos t \,x(t)=0 \quad (1)
$$
can be transformed to the system:
$$\vec{x}'=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-\cos t & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \vec{x}=A(t) \cdot x(t)
$$
with minimum **period** $T=2\pi$. Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be its **characteristic values**. A theorem gives:
$$\mu_1\mu_2=\exp\Bigg\{\int_0^{2\pi} tr(A(t))dt\Bigg\}=1 \quad (2)
$$
Therefore, the **Wronskian** of any two linearly independent solutions satisfies:
$$
W(t+2\pi)=W(t) \quad (3)
$$

Does $(3)$ imply that all solutions are bounded and thus we have **asymptotic stability**? If not, in what way could we use $(2)$ to determine $(1)$'s stability?

Comment: Determining the numerical solution of $\Phi'(t)=A(t)\Phi(t)$, $\Phi(0)=I_2$ gives $$\Phi(2\pi)=\pmatrix{-8.06518375& 14.50923829\\  4.41423509&  -8.06518374}$$ with eigenvalues $-16.06813251$ and $-0.06223499$, so that you have one contracting and one expanding eigenspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

If you want to make a conclusion about the stability of the given system and thus the initial equation via Floquet Theory (as your initial approach), then there is a theorem, that states that if for a multiplier $\mu_j$ for your given system, it is $|\mu_j| <1$, then the system is unstable. But, that's true, if you can prove that :

$$\mu_1\mu_2 = 1 \Rightarrow |\mu_1\mu_2| = 1 \Leftrightarrow |\mu_1| = \frac{1}{|\mu_2|} <1, \; \text{if} \; \mu_1, \mu_2 \neq 1$$

In order to conclude that, use the case of the characteristic matrix being periodic, thus $\Phi(t+T) = \Phi(t) \Rightarrow \Phi(2 \pi) = \Phi(0)E \Rightarrow E= \Phi(0)^{-1}\Phi(2\pi)$.

Now, the characteristic values will be the eigenvalues of the matrix $E$. You can calculate them (or approximate them) and conclude if $\mu_1,\mu_2 \neq 1$.

You can find more information and elaborations (proofs etc) about that theorem (which also states 2 cases about stability and asymptotic stability) and Floquet Theory in general, [here.](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/MAT4996/Floquet.pdf)

**Graphs :**

(A phase portrait for a certain $t$) For a simple case of time $t$ such that $\cos t = -1$, the system has the image of the phase portrait :

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \quad$[image]

which is a saddle, thus unstable.

Now, a sample solution family by sampling some initial values for the solution of the given equation and its derivative, one can see the unstability :

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$[image]

Comment: You cannot use the linearization to infer the stability of a time dependent system.

Comment: Once again, you cannot use eigenvalues of time dependent systems to conclude the stability. -1.

Comment: @Artem Fine, I altered my answer to only use the Floquet Theory approach which is the standard and theoritical way of handling time dependent systems (also given abstracts and conent for further justification and studying).

Comment: @Artem Any issues now for that -1 ?

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as a "phase portrait" for a time dependent system. Also, your reasoning about multipliers is incorrect.

Comment: @Artem It's not a phase portrait for a time dependent system. It's just a phase portrait for taking a value of the time dependent coefficient and making a trivial system, for the sake of a visual grasp. Secondly, the multiplier case is correct and elaborated on the PDF linked (as well as in many other Floquet Theory elaborations).

Comment: Dear Rebellos, I think that you need to carefully (re)read the link you provided and after it critically address your "answer".

Comment: @Rebellos Why did you assume that the characteristic values are both not equal to $1$?

Comment: @Jevaut Didn't, said you have to prove that in order to use the lemmas.

Comment: @Jevaut Also the PDF hinted gives a really nice elaboration about the facts. But what did the exercise ask initially ?

Comment: @Rebellos Just that: to examine this equation and determine its stability.

Comment: Hi,  perhaps u meant in your answer that if the Absolute value of the eigenvalue is less than one then the system is ' Stable'.